# Learning YUI from scratch

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, yui3

I am new to YUI and I want to learn it from scratch. Can you suggest some books or tutorials? Where should I start? It seems YUI 3 is different from its predecessors. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with [YUI 3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/) (most current is the [YUI 3.2.0 preview release)](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/07/26/3-2-0pr1/), but if you go the YUI 2.x route, [YUI 2.8: Learning the Library](https://www.packtpub.com/yahoo-user-interface-yui-2-8-learning-library/book) was recently released.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this page,
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/

Answer (score 1):

The YUI 3 Cookbook is an excellent source of information for getting started with YUI 3.
[http://www.amazon.com/YUI-3-Cookbook-Cookbooks-OReilly/dp/1449304192](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449304192)